# Changing text of a button in an array of buttons jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, button

I need some explanations.
I'm trying to change the text of a button which is in an array of buttons.
$buttons is my array of buttons.
My question is simple:
why can I change the text of all my buttons in my array, but when I target a button "$buttons[1]" it doesn't work.

```js
$buttons.text("My NEW Text");
```

works and change the text of all buttons in my $buttons array but when I do

```js
$buttons[1].text("My NEW Text");
```

it give me the error:

> "$buttons[1].text is not a function"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$buttons[1]` (or the jQuery equivalent `$buttons.get(1)`) accesses the actual DOM node, not the jQuery object. There is no `text()` method on DOM nodes. You should use [`jquery.eq`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to access the jQuery object at a particular index:

```
$buttons.eq(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest (and cleanest) solution would probably be to attach an ID to that button. That way you can easily change the text using:

```
$("#ButtonId").text("My New Text")
```